# Category static blocks in Magento 2 sample data Luma theme

Tags: magento-2.1, sample-data, category-listing

I can't figure out how Magento 2 is assigning blocks to categories in the sample data. I see the blocks under CMS, and I see the assignment for a category to only use static blocks, but where are we actually specifying the blocks to use?

[image: category edit view]

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By Default in Luma Theme, All static content in category page coming from

> Content -> Widgets

All Category Landing page content comes from Widgets.

You can check it inside widget, Widget call static block to get content.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have never used widgets before so I never even thought to look there!

Comment: The fun fact here is that the widget configuration> Layout Update, refers to Anchor Categories. But Women, Men, and other categories where these widgets are displayed are NOT anchor categories. If you try to remove, and add again, you'll see you can only re-select those categories by chosing "Non-Anchor categories".